# Beginner Q -ARGV and multiple files

Tags: c, codeblocks

Good afternoon, Old man trying to learn new tricks here,
I have been given an assignment that I am trying to work my way through but I am stuck as I don't fully understand the argv[]

I have 4 files I want to read from and eventually use malloc and realloc but thats further down.
My initial plan was to try read one file and get it onto the command line. I had it opening but made that many changes that now I'm lost.

Think my problem lies with argv[4] as i dont understand it, when I put 4 it goes into theloop and errors but with 1 it just bombs out.
If someone can point me in the direction I am going wrong here it would be great

Thanks

```
struct Person { char lname[20]; char fname[20]; int id; };
int i, N;
struct Person *student;



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *outputfile;
printf("Please enter the name of the file to open: ");
scanf("%s", argv[4]);

outputfile = fopen(argv[4], "r") ;
if (outputfile==NULL){
    perror(argv[1]);
    fprintf(stderr,"Error while opeining file\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `argv[4]` - It may not exist and probably is read only/not long enough. Create a new variable for the filename

Comment: you don't "write" to argv.

Comment: argv[0] is the name of your program, argv[1] is the first argument.  Only you know if your pathname is in argv[4].  It's a string, so you pass that to fopen, like you did.  Treat it as read-only so you don't want to write anything to it with your `scanf()` call.  You use argc to tell how many arguments your program was called with.

Comment: The strings pointed to by the `argv` char-pointer can be modified if you are careful but that's very seldom that you wanna do that. It's best to consider them as pure read-only input for your program (i.e. command line arguments). If you want a user to type a file name at runtime, you should create another char-array variable for that. Like: `char filename[100];` and do `scanf("%99s", filename);`

Comment: ... and if you want the user to give the file name on the command line as the 4th argument when starting the program you do: `if (arc < 5) {puts("too few arguments"); exit(1);}` and then delete the `scanf` and just use `argv[4]` directly

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use argv[]. Argv is an array of strings that store the arguments passed in when running the executable. If you run the executable like this: `./a.out`, then argv only contains one element, which is the path of the executable itself. If you run the program like this, and you try to access argv[4], it does not give you an error, but if you debug it using GDB, it will output the following: `warning: Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.`

You could pass in a file on the command line like this: `./a.out yourfile.txt`. In this case, argv[0] will be the path of the executable `a.out`, and argv[1]   will be the string "yourfile.txt".

It might be easier to completely drop the use of argv and store the user input for the filename in a string. You can then pass that string as an argument to fopen. This would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char fileName[30];
    char ch;

    printf("Please enter a file name\n");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    FILE *outputFile = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(outputFile == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open %s\n", fileName);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, The 4 file names I have are of student numbers and Id's. They are.csv files from 10 students to 10K students. Maybe I am trying to reinvent the wheel as the way you have above is given to us.. We were asked to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use constants (`NAME_LEN`) instead of hard-coding magic values.
2. Prefer multiple lines for your struct.  It's easier to read and version control systems prefer lines for diffs.
3. Avoid global variables.
4. Do a boundary check using `argc` (count of elements in argv) before you read argv.  `argv[0]` is the name of your program, `argv[1]` is the first argument.
5. Treat `argv` as read-only, i.e. don't do `scanf("%s", argv[4])`.
6. Prefer to initialize variables instead of declaring and assigning a value separately.  It's easy to forget setting a variable before use which leads ot undefined behavior.   Initialization might be faster, too.
7. Your file handle is called `outputfile` but with `fopen()` you use the `mode` of `r` for reading.  Either `mode` should be `w` or you want to change the variable name to `inputfile`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LEN 20

struct Person {
    char lname[NAME_LEN];
    char fname[NAME_LEN];
    int id;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX];
    if(argc > 4) {
        strcpy(filename, argv[4]);
    } else {
        printf("filename? ");
        fgets(filename, FILENAME_MAX, stdin);
        filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = '\0';
    }

    FILE *outputfile = fopen(filename, "w");
    if(!outputfile) {
        // ...
    }
    fclose(outputfile);
}
```

and you would run your program with either:

```
$ ./a.out dummy dummy dummy output.txt
```

or

```
$ ./a.out
filename? output.txt
```

Comment: Might need a flush after the `printf` to stop buffering

Comment: @EdHeal When is that needed?  I don't think that I ever had to do it with Linux for stdout.  For files which are block buffered, yes.

Comment: I believe that data is left in the buffer until a new line is reached. Therefore, the prompt would not be displayed.

Comment: wondering what would happen if the 4th filename (the one stored in argv[4]) is longer than FILENAME_MAX? Buffer overflow?

Comment: fgets() will only FILENAME_MAX - 1 length bytes and ensure it's '\0' terminated.  The manual page explains it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are expected to provide 4 file names as command line parameters. In which case you should be doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int files = 4;

  if(argc != files+1)
  {
    printf("Usage: myprog file1 file2 file3 file4");
    return 0;
  }

  FILE* fp [files];

  for(int i=0; i<files; i++)
  {
    fp[i] = fopen(argv[i+1], "r");
    ...
  }
  ...

}
```

Comment: 1. Download and compile the rsstatic.c file from moodle.
2. Modify the code, replacing static allocation with dynamic allocation.
3. Now modify the code so that it takes a file name on the command-line, instead of a file
name hard-wired into the program source code.
4. Now modify the code so that it loads the data from a number of file names, and appends the
data from each new file onto the end of the array you have already allocated. (You will need
realloc() function for this ).
5. Modify the code: Write a function to find the number of students with student numbers
greater than 1000.

Comment: I am just working through it step by step really.

Comment: @TheFridge Ok so this would be the steps 3 and 4.